# Problem with subtotal in Magento it's adding variants together

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, products, grand-total

I've been trying to figure this out for a few hours now and it's just dawned on me so on my site i'd have a product say for £159.00 and my grand total was showing up as daft amounts like £932,535.00 so i typed in on a calculator 932,535.00/159.00 which gave me the answer of 5865 i did this with a few products and started noticing a pattern that number adds up to my variants see screenshot below any idea why magento is doing this.

[image]

This is also what the backend for the products look like

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There's something not quite right with your quantity dropdown as I see. Why do you need quantity in custom options and is it different from the product quantity?

When you select a quantity (from custom options dropdown) let's say you select 50, it will add 50 to product's base price and myltiplies it with the product quantity if that makes any sense.

Comment: Where else would i put quantity there set quantities so the customer can choose how many batches of paper they need, i thought it would just add the additional price on the base price so say the base prices 100.00 and i select a custom option with the price of 50.00 i thought it would just add that on ?

Comment: My bad, I get what you mean. In that case it all seems fine in the custom options. It's unusual behavior I have to say, to debug I'll run reindex and furthermore look into things like other extensions that maybe conflicting or theme modifications!

Comment: I'm new to magento but from what you've seen magento straight out the box does support this sort of thing right ? like i don't need to have a plugin or anything because at the minute they are just simple products.

Comment: yeah that's how it should work out of the box and it does as we use it day in day out for products with custom options. You don't need a plugin for this.

Comment: I found the issue don't know exactly what it was but someone told me they changed one of the core files which was app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Quote/Item/abstract.php so i just copied the same file from another site and now it works :)

Comment: That's great you managed to get it working, seems like core file was changed somehow that caused the issue, re-installing the core file fixed the issue :)